# Automatic execution of program in netlogo

Tags: netlogo

I am running my simulation. I have to run my simulation for 20 times with twenty different seeds values. I am saving the output of simulation in 20 different files. Is there any way in Netlogo, where we can specify the number of runs and seed values and program execution completed itself after specified no of runs and give output in one or in different files?

Answer (score 0):

You could use behavior space and as one of your experiment parameters use the seed value.

Here's a link to behavior space: https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/behaviorspace.html

Comment: I tried to run the program using behaviour space and get this error message

Comment: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: PermGen space
 at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2436)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2556)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2572)
 at java.lang.Class.privateGetPublicMethods(Class.java:2572)
 at java.lang.Class.getMethods(Class.java:1412)
 at org.nlogo.generator.BytecodeUtils$.getMethods(BytecodeUtils.scala:34)
 at org.nlogo.generator.BytecodeUtils$.isRejiggered(BytecodeUtils.scala:19)
 at

Comment: It seems your experiment is too large. How many variables are you testing? Try a small experiment first.

Comment: I agreed my experiment is too large. Each run approximately 3 hour to complete. i am storing 4 properties of turtles after 24 ticks and program runs  for 26000 ticks.

Comment: You may want to try to break down your experiment into smaller segments. The reason why you get an out of memory error is because the results are kept in memory until all experiments are written to file. You may notice a speed up with smaller experiments too because less memory transactions.

Comment: Is it possible in behaviour space that we write results into file after some interval i.e. 24 ticks ???

Comment: Not be default. You could write your own file-writer if you don't like the default one. However, I would just suggest having multiple smaller experiments which, when combined, would represent your full experiment that you're trying to execute.